# Android include tag not overriding layout attributes

Tags: android, attributes, include, margin

I am having trouble using `<include>` in conjunction with `<merge>`. I am developing on Eclipse with the latest Android SDK (4.3). Here is my sample code:

*test_merge.xml*

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" >
    </View>

</merge>
```

*test_main.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/test_merge" 
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*MyActivity.java*

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_main);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I should see a red square on the top left corner, 100x100dp. Instead, the whole screen is red. Thus, for some reason the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes in the `<include>` have no effect.

I have read the documentation and it said that in order to override attributes via the `<include>` tag, I must override `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, which I have done.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `merge`, there is no parent to apply `100dp`s to. Try switching to `FrameLayout` instead of `merge` or (even better) in this case you may just remove `merge` and have `View` be the root.

**Edit:**

Change test_merge.xml to:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFF0000" >
</View>
```

Comment: Won't the `100dp` width and height be applied to the `<View>`? From what I understand, when the compiler sees the `include` tag, it goes to the layout, copies everything within `<merge>` and places it in `<include>`'s place.

Comment: @user2566395 Yes. You understand correctly, but there can be more than one `View` inside `merge`, so it won't apply `layout_width` there.

Answer (score 0):

Try making those attributes 0 in your included `layout`

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFF0000" >
    </View>

</merge>
```

Comment: Won't that give errors? These values require units like `dp` or `px`.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Yes, thanks for catching that...got in a hurry. I have edited my answer

Comment: Now nothing is visible. `<include>` simply does not use the attributes at all.